# VScode intellisense not recognizing pip intalled packages (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm just getting started with python. After installing python (3.6.8) and running VS code to learn some scripts, I found out that intellisense is not giving any suggesions for packages that I installed by pip 
ex:

import numpy as np

x=np.ar(nothing shows here and even before typing the "ar", just shows a bunch of stuff that I typed earlier)

I'm sorry if I'm missing something, I'm literally a newbie.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you [selected the appropriate interpreter and environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) that you installed into. Also make sure that the extension has finished loading and analyzing packages. Finally, you can [use the Microsoft language server](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3977) if you aren't already to see if it gives you better results than Jedi.